# API Facebook - Get all profiles pictures (not only /picture) of a user (different of /me)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need your help because I'm trying to collect **all the profil pictures** - per user - of a list of users who are :

- different of /me
- not necessary using the web app
- but having a profil pictures album that is public

I red a lot of topics and the official FB doc --> So, I tried 2 solutions (the ID is here for example) :

1. This GRAPH API call to access to the Profile Pictures album among others :

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/1214007393/albums?access_token=...
   ```
2. This FQL query (with my user token) :

   ```
   SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=1214007393 AND name="Profile Pictures"
   ```

Both are returning to me :

```
    {'data': []}
```

My question is : As these profile pictures are public, I think I may have missed something, but maybe there is only one profile pic available --> the current one via  /picture ? and others are not available even if they're public ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't guaranteed to obtain the Facebook Profile Pictures album. This is by design for privacy reasons.

You can always get the current profile picture though.

Comment: Thanks phwd, even if the profile pictures are public ?

Comment: The Profile Pictures album is always public .